# SQLite Android No such Column Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite in android but for some reason I'm getting the no such column error. I think the error may be syntax but I can't seem to locate it.

This is my code:

```
         @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
    {
        database.execSQL("create table " +
                TABLE_NAME +
                " (" +
                TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text," +
                TABLE_ROW_THREE +  " text," +
                TABLE_ROW_FOUR + " text" +
                ");");
    }
```

I had tried some formatting tricks like adding a space to the fourth text, or subtracting one but none of them seemed to have worked yet.

Beneath is the logcat reading.

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table database_table has no column named table_row_three (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO database_table(table_row_three,table_row_two,table_row_four,table_row_one) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:892)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1568)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1440)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you to use ORMLiteSqliteDatabase

Comment: I think you need to check value of TABLE_ROW_THREE this varibale in your helper class.

Comment: Check the value of TABLE_ROW_THREE

Comment: Have you changed the schema (the `CREATE TABLE`) and forgot to bump up database version or uninstall the app?

Comment: I think the issue is the value of TABLE_ROW_THREE. Thanks for help! I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this, it will work,

```
 public static final String  TABLE_ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "rowone";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "rowtwo";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_THREE = "rowthree";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_FOUR = "rowfour";


    private static  String DATABASE_NAME = "YourDatabase";
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "YourTable";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " rowone TEXT ," 
                + " rowtwo TEXT , "
                + " rowthree TEXT," 
                + " rowfour TEXT);";


        db.execSQL(createQuery);


    }
```

Comment: you modified anything in Databse Table ,Uninstall the previous app and install new app

Comment: Basically I forgot to set the code for the update method.   Thanks for your insight